# Describe the span of the given vectors algebraically

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the general equation of the line of $span\left(\begin{bmatrix}2\\ -4\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1\\
-2\end{bmatrix}\right)$

So I started with solving the matrix \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 0\\ -4 & 2 & 0\end{bmatrix} which becomes \begin{bmatrix}1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
This shows that our vectors are linearly dependent since we have a parameter that can give us infinite values.

I took it apart into it's equation $x-\frac{1}{2}y=0$ and set y=t $\therefore$ $x-\frac{1}{2}t=0$.

We also have our vector equation $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}+ t\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ (This is probably where I messed up)
$x=2-t$, $y=-4+2t$

I'm pretty sure I can just use substitution from one of the equations, then solve for t, then just solve for x and y, but that doesn't seem right, and it makes solving the matrix useless. I can also try solving for x and y by substituting my parametric equations into $x-\frac{1}{2}y=0$ and solve for t, but then again, I'm not sure.

In the end I want to represent my equation as $Ax+By=0$

Comment: Isn't $x-\frac12y=0$ in the form $Ax+By=0$?  I'm not sure why you introduced $t$

Comment: You're right, that could be the answer, but I'm not sure. I know what I'm trying to look for(the line that is drawn from the space these dependent vectors occupy, which goes through the origin), but I don't know how to get there. I have no way of checking if the answer is right or not.

Comment: The way you wrote them, these vectors are in $\mathbb R^2$, and it’s easy to verify they’re on $x-\frac12y=0$

Comment: Yeah both vectors satisfy it. Our professor told us that we needed to substitute our parametric equations into another equation to solve for t, but I guess that's not necessary? There are later questions that involve 3 vectors in $\mathbb R^3$. I'm guessing it's about the same process?

Comment: In $3$ dimensions a parameter is helpful for describing a line; $Ax+By+Cz=0$ is a plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectors in your problem are in $\mathbb R^2.$  A subspace spanned by vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ could be the zero subspace, a line, or a plane.  In this case, as you said, the two vectors are linearly dependent, and they aren't just the zero vector, so they span a line.  You can easily see that the equation of that line is $2x-y=0$.  There's no need for a parameter $t$ for a line in $2$ dimensions.